# How to compare equality of two rows in Excel file in Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there any built in function that can be used to easily compare two rows in an Excel file. I am using Apache POI.

```
        try {

            Workbook wb1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(file1Path));
            Sheet sheet1 = wb1.getSheetAt(0);

            Workbook wb2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(file2Path));
            Sheet sheet2 = wb2.getSheetAt(0);

            for (Row myrow : sheet1) {
                if (myrow.getRowNum() == 0) {
                    // add entire row to a sheet for 'found in file 1 but not file 2' -> sheet 0
                    write(myrow, output_filename_path, dstSheetNumberInOutputFile);
                    continue;
                }
                // look for this key in the other sheet
                for (Row otherRow : sheet2) {
                    if (rowsAreEqual(myrow, otherRow)) {
                        write(myrow, output_filename_path, dstSheetNumberInOutputFile);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I have an `if statement` that has the function `rowsAreEqual()` needs to compare equality of the two rows. How can I make the `rowsAreEqual()` function?

I tried this but hasn't worked:

```
    private static boolean rowsAreEqual(Row myrow, Row otherRow) {
        int equalCount = 0;
        System.out.println("last cell num: " + myrow.getLastCellNum());
        for(int i=0; i < myrow.getLastCellNum(); i++){
            if(myrow.getCell(i) == otherRow.getCell(i)){
                equalCount++;
                System.out.println("Cells are the same: " + myrow.getCell(i) + " && " + otherRow.getCell(i));
            }
        }

        if(equalCount == myrow.getLastCellNum()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Each `Row` in apache poi contains `Cell` which can be accessed by index or can be iterated over. You can write a small utility to iterate over these cell values.
Pls refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16656068/7803797

Comment: What about compare numbers of cells in rows and if they are different return false. Else, if are equals, iterate over them and call something like this: `row1.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().equals(row2.getCell(i).getStringCellValue())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out like this. I had to make an extra function called `getCellContentsAsString()` so that I could compare the cells correctly:

```
    private static boolean rowsAreEqual(Row myrow, Row otherRow) {
        int equalCount = 0;
        System.out.println("last cell num: " + myrow.getLastCellNum());
        for(int i=0; i < myrow.getLastCellNum(); i++){
            System.out.println(myrow.getCell(i) + " is the cell content in file1");
            System.out.println(otherRow.getCell(i) + " is the cell content in file2");
            Cell c1 = myrow.getCell(i);
            Cell c2 = otherRow.getCell(i);
            
            String s1 = getCellContentAsString(c1);
            String s2 = getCellContentAsString(c2);
            
            if(s1.equals(s2)){
                equalCount++;
                System.out.println("Cells are the same: " + myrow.getCell(i) + " && " + otherRow.getCell(i));
            }
        }

        if(equalCount == myrow.getLastCellNum()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static String getCellContentAsString(Cell cell) {
        String data = null;
        if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.STRING) {
            data = cell.getStringCellValue(); 
        }
        else if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.NUMERIC) {
            data = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract to comparing a range of cells.
This would allow you comparing either rows or columns, or individual regions (e.g. A1:Z256) - a so called **Range**.

So the object to compare - to be equal in **contents** - is [`CellRange`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellRange.html).

In Java the [`boolean equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method of any object relies on their [`int hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) function. In a utility-class called `RangeContentsUtils` you could implement both:

```java
public class RangeContentsUtils {

  public static boolean contentsEquals(CellRange rangeA, CellRange rangeB) {
    if (rangeA == null || rangeB == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (rangeA.size() != rangeB.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    // alternative would be:
    // return stringContentsOf(rangeA).hashCode() == stringContentsOf(rangeB).hashCode();

    return contentsToString(rangeA).equals(contentsToString(rangeB));
  }

  public static String contentsToString(CellRange range) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = range.iterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
      Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
      switch(cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
          sb.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
          break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
          sb.append(cell.getNumericCellValue());
          break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
          sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
          break;
      }
      sb.append("\0"); // use NUL char as cell-separator 
    }

    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

Now your row-comparison could use this utility class.

See also:
[Compare specific row or column of xls sheet using java and Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624182/compare-specific-row-or-column-of-xls-sheet-using-java-and-apache-poi/16656068#16656068)